# Why does get environment return a {} wrapped string?

Tags: python, fastapi

What have I got wrong in my FastAPi set up please? I have had to wrap my `os.environ.get()` because environment variables are being returned with a'{}' - e.g. '{postgres://....}'.   I am deploying it to docker locally, and the environment variables return without any '{}' wrap, when I echo them in the container's CLI.

My main.py is as follows, and it now works, but I don't think this is normal:

```
import re
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from app.config import get_settings, Settings

app = FastAPI()

register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=re.findall(r'\{(.*?)\}',os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))[0],
    modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
)
```

Comment: `os.environ` is a dict and you can use `get` on a dict object to get a specific key's value. Since you're using a container make sure you've set the [environment variables in docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: this does seem strange. What do you see if you use `env` command in the shell and check `DATABASE_URL`? And if you start python script in a .sh file, make sure to add `env` right before `python` command.

Comment: does it make any difference if you remove all the fastapi & tortoise stuff and just print `os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")`?